# combining layers in illustrator, adding stroke & shadow

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, stroke

I'm trying to put together a logo that consists of more than one layer but I want to put a stroke around it.  I can't seem to figure out how to combine these layers together so the stroke will only go around the whole logo rather than each section individually.  I have done lots of searching but can't seem to find a solution.  Thanks for any advice you can give me!

Comment: I agree may be a duplicate of the above, however it may require more depending upon what "combine these layers" means. Can you explain in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a layer group, adding all your layers to it, then applying the stroke to the group.